# JavaScript returning boolean over 21 y/o within template string

Tags: javascript, boolean, template-strings

I can't figure out how to implement a greater then formula within a template string to return a boolean value (see code).

```
const age = 47; // simplified for question
let html;

html =  `<ul>
            <li>Alcohol allowed?: ${if (age > 20) {return 'true'} else {return 'false'}}</li>
        </ul>`;

document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = html;
```

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Alcohol allowed?: true/false</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this specific case you can use `${age > 20}` in your template. In general, you want a ternary (or any other) *expression*: `blah ${ age > 20 ? "yes" : "no" } blah`

Comment: On top of the comment above, which is in fact what you want, template literals allow the use of **expressions**. Your `if...else` is **not** an expression. It's a statement instead.

Comment: Plus ternaries look much more readable and pretty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that there is no need to `return` as you're not in a function. Instead, as all you're after is displaying `true` or `false`, you can simply just use the value of `age > 20`:

```js
const age = 47; // simplified for question
let html = `<ul>
             <li>Alcohol allowed?: ${age > 20}</li>
            </ul>`;

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Alternatively, you can use a ternary if you would like to display other values than just `true` or `false`.

See example below:

```js
const age = 47; // simplified for question
let html = `<ul>
             <li>Alcohol allowed?: ${age > 20 ? 'Above' : 'Below'}</li>
            </ul>`;

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

You can read more about the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) here.